# Is It Possible to Know When an AsyncLocal Has Been Definitively Invalidated?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Consider the following code that I am using in a xUnit test class:

```
public sealed class AsyncLocalTests
{
    readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public AsyncLocalTests(ITestOutputHelper output) => _output = output;

    [Fact]
    void Expected()
        => new AsyncLocal<object>(args =>
            {
                if (args.ThreadContextChanged && args.CurrentValue == null)
                {
                    _output.WriteLine("Invalidated!");
                }
            }) {Value = new object()};

    [Fact]
    Task ExpectedAsync() => Task.Run(action: Expected);

    [Fact]
    Task UnexpectedAsync()
        => Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                new AsyncLocal<object>(args =>
                {
                    if (args.ThreadContextChanged && args.CurrentValue == null)
                    {
                        _output.WriteLine("Invalidated!");
                    }
                }) {Value = new object()};
                await Task.Yield();
            });

}
```

I am attempting to use the `AsyncLocal` to store an ambient value for an application I am designing.  At some point, the execution scope in which the `AsyncLocal` is created ends, invalidating the ambient value.  What I would like to do is know when this happens and having an event and/or trigger of some sort that notifies me when it does.

In the three tests above, `Expected` and `ExpectedAsync` print out the `"Invalidated!"` message once, which is the expected (desired) behavior for my scenario.

However, `UnexpectedAsync` prints this message out twice.  This is a problem for my scenario as invalidation should only occur once and only when the execution of the context in which the `AsyncLocal` was created has completed execution.

As I understand it, the task in `UnexpectedAsync` is yielding control to the asynchronous infrastructure (first invalidation), and then control is resumed back into the originating context (`UnexpectedAsync`), which then in turn completes (second invalidation).

What I am looking to achieve here is to ensure that the `AsyncLocal` is definitively invalidated once for all of the above demonstrated scenarios.  That is, I would like to know for certainty when the execution context of the `AsyncLocal` has completed and is no longer valid.  Is this possible?

Comment: If that is a problem for you - doesn't that mean you are abusing `AsyncLocal` for purpose it was not intended for?

Comment: Not for 2 of the 3 scenarios that I need it for, @Evk. :)  Certainly open to any additional approaches to reach the desired behavior.

Comment: I wish I knew what is desired behavior then. You said you need to "store a value", but that is quite vague. Why you have chosen async local?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Evk.  I have updated the post with more context/details.  FWIW, desired = expected above.  Additionally, the value is an ambient one, expected to flow through the logical processing of execution from the point to where it was created until the point where the context in which it was created fully completes.  In the 3rd (unexpected/undesired) test, I get the 2 "completed" events, but no way of discerning between the two (that I can tell).  Hope that helps.  Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 2):

What you're experiencing is the [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netframework-4.7.1#remarks).

The notification method is called whenever there is a context switch. Task.Yield causes a context switch. Then, the Yield completes, and there is a context switch back to check the state of the awaitable (completed or faulted), and then the thread running the async work completes.

In your clarification, you use the term "completed event": It would be better to refer to it as a "context switch event". That would give you a better mental model.

To answer your question: The context is invalidated once the Task completes or faults. Awaiting the task will tell you that, or you can check a Task's IsCompleted or IsFaulted properties.

Comment: Thank you Bill for this answer.  I am in agreement and understand that there is a context switch event, but is there not a way of knowing when this context has been _definitively_ switched from this context?  Meaning, switched from this context, never to return again?